# Is the subgroup of orthogonal matrices in $GL_3(\mathbb R)$ cyclic? What's generating it?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, linear-groups

> Is the subgroup of $GL_3(\mathbb R)$ denoted by $Q=\{A \in GL_3(\mathbb R)\mid AA^t=I_3\}$ cyclic? What's generating it?

I showed $Q$ is a group, and realized it's the group of all orthogonal matrices. My conjecture is that the generating element is some sort of rotation matrix, however it seems that rotation around the x-axis, for instance: 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        \cos x & -\sin x & 0 \\
        \sin x & \cos x & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
Seems to be like it doesn't generate some orthogonal matrices, actually all those that don't have the element 1 in the (3,3) entry...

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: The group cannot be cyclic, since it is not countable.

Comment: It's neither cyclic or fg.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group

Comment: Can I say it's not cyclic since it's not commutative?